# PowerShell Move Files From One Server to Another

Tags: powershell

I know this has been asked a million times, but I can't seem to find anything that works for me. I don't know if there is a permissions issue or what, but I am trying to move files from one server to another using a PowerShell script in the task scheduler and it worked for about a week before it stopped working. There are no errors in the task scheduler, and I'm not well versed in PowerShell at all, I'm just trying to get something quick and simple for our CMS manager to move her files from the website to a folder on another server.

```
$ORG = "E:\folders\uploads\" ## enter current source folder
$DEST= "\\server-folder-structure\uploads\" ## enter your destination folder 
foreach ($ORG in gci $DEST -include *.doc,*.docx,*.pdf,*.png,*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.html,*.htm -recurse)
{ 
  Move-Item -path $ORG -destination $DEST ## Move the files to the destination folder
}
```

I tried this too, in hopes it would work, but still no files are being moved.

```
Get-ChildItem E:\folder-structure\uploads\* -Include *.doc,*.docx,*.pdf,*.png,*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.html,*.htm -Recurse |ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName \\server-folder-structure\uploads\ }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Are there permissions to folders that I need to set that I don't know about? Is PowerShell just not the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gci $DEST` will give you all the files that are _already in the destination share_ - did you mean `foreach($source in $gci $ORG ...)` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're making this harder than it should be (*with respect to PowerShell being new to you*). You don't need a loop on any of your examples if you want to pipe directly to `Move-Item`:

```
$ORG  = "E:\folders\uploads\" ## enter current source folder
$DEST = "\\server-folder-structure\uploads\" ## enter your destination folder 
$filterFor = "*.doc","*.docx","*.pdf","*.png","*.gif","*.jpg","*.jpeg","*.html","*.htm"
Get-ChildItem $ORG -Include $filterFor -File -Recurse | 
    Move-Item -Destination $DEST -WhatIf
```

As for what you tried, and as [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) pointed out, you would be searching your `$DEST` location in which the files wouldn't exist as they would only be in `$ORG`; given that that's the actual source folder.

- This would also overwrite you `$ORG` variable with the current item in your iteration in: `foreach ($ORG in gci ..){ ... }`.
- Meaning, your `Move-Item` would be invalid.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you! I used both of the examples you guys left for me and the files still won't get moved. It can't be the PowerShell that is the problem, it's either the task I have in the scheduler or some kind of quirk between sending files from a 2012 server to a 2019 one.... Is there an extra security perm I should be adding to the destination folder to allow PowerShell to drop the files into it?

Comment: Besides using the proper credentials either in your task schedule, or in your PowerShell script, I would ensure PowerShell Remoting is enabled and able to receive requests via WinRM. Would start there, ensure any commands can be ran against that machine and if not, ensure the WinRM service is running.

Comment: Turns out the service account lost it's admin privileges. Thanks for helping me come up with a better script! :)

Comment: Just glad you got it worked out! lol happy to help:)